# using a variable to navigate pages in an Acrobat document

Tags: null, undefined, acrobat

I am trying to have users navigate through an Acrobat document using buttons.  Everything works fine if they click one of the navigation buttons.  When they do, i set a variable using

```
pgnum = this.pageNum
```

then I send them to the requested page.  When they hit the return button, I use the following

```
this.pageNum=pgnum
```

The problem comes if they scroll (no button clicking) to a page and hit return.  I can really only send them back to the first page (page 0) of the document.  In this scenario, pgnum is undefined or something.  I tried the following without luck.

```
if (pgnum == num) {
this.pageNum = 1; //have also tried this.pageNum.value = 1
}
else
this.pageNum=pgnum
```

I am sure that it is a syntax issue or an issue with dealing with undefined variables.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to prevent undefineds etc. is to define pgnum as a document-level variable.

Create a document-level script, which contains only this line:

```
var pgnum = 0 ;
```

Then you can simplify the code in the Back buttons:

```
this.pageNum = pgnum ;
```

The document will go to the page number set by pgnum. If it has not been changed, it will go to the first page of the document.

The disadvantage is that after going to a set pgnum, it will always go back to that page, until a new pgnum value is set. It may be a better idea to reset pgnum as soon as it has been used to get back to a selected page:

```
this.pageNum = pgnum ;
pgnum = 0 ;
```

and that should do it.

Comment: Would be great if I knew how to add a document level variable in Acrobat

Comment: Which Acrobat version do you use?